# Does NEST support nested datatypes?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have a document that contains a list of child objects of type Article. When I index a document, will the child articles be indexed too? Can I query for these articles without querying for the parent documents?

Comment: I think what you asked is a little too vague. Do you want to have both parent and children back when querying the children? I think the answer you got misses some information but in order to give you a better one I would need more inputs on your usecase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The child-articles will probably be stored (afaik) but certainly not indexed in any meaningful way. You can't search for them directly. 
Instead you probably want to create new types of 'documents' for elasticsearch (such as a separate 'article' document) than the ones you're currently using.

So no, you can't query for articles in the way you mentioned, unless you index articles separately.

for what it's worth: ES does provide parent-child relationships, but this is useful for returning a parent-doc based on quering the children, so basically the other way around.

hth